# Formula to Concatenate all Public Group Membership Names onto User Record

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter, public-group

I need to create a custom field on the user table that concatenates the public groups this user is a member of separated by ', '. Does anyone know if it's possible to pull public group data through to the user table with a formula?

Comment: Did you end up getting this working? I'd be curious about which route you went to achieve this - i have a similar project assigned to me now.

Answer (score 0):

No, formulas can't reference child objects. You would have to write some sort of code (e.g. a Lightning Component or Visualforce page) to show this information.

Comment: Or a trigger on user to get the groups where this user is a member and populate a field